# Add object to panel on every click

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener

This is my actionListener for a popup menu button i want to add this picture on the panel after every its clicked

```
        mntmNewMenuItem.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        //This method will be called whenever you click the button.
          int i;
          public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            try {
                label.setIcon(new ImageIcon
                 (new URL("file:/C:/Users/Ashad/JunoWorkspace/FYP1/table.png")));
            } catch (MalformedURLException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }   
                panel.add(label); 
            //redraw panel after addition
                panel.validate();    
                panel.repaint();
                handleDrag(label);
              }
        });
```

Comment: what is the question?

Comment: i couldnot add the object as many times as i like to .. it just add to the panel once

Comment: yes 1 panel can be added just once, you need to create new label everytime and then add.

Comment: But you've only got one label object?

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).  The rest of that code should be called from inside the `try`.  It is pointless to call it after the `catch`.

Comment: what if i create a class of the object and then add new labels by its constructor ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can only add a UI object once.

if you want just a single instance to be added, you need to remove that element 1st then add. (but it doesn't seem logical removing then adding).

instead you can create a `Label()` object inside actionperformed

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            label = new Label();//Added
            try {
                label.setIcon(new ImageIcon
                 (new URL("file:/C:/Users/Ashad/JunoWorkspace/FYP1/table.png")));
            } catch (MalformedURLException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
```